# How to use indexes in XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I do have popup where are three dropdowns, ids are unique 
with each popup generation:

The first element:

```
<a aria-required="true" class="select" aria-disabled="false" aria-
describedby="5715:0-label" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" role="button" 
title="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="5733:0" data-
interactive-lib-uid="10">Stage 1 - Needs Assessment</a>
```

While I'm able to identify the element above by simple `xpath="//*[@class='select'][1]"`, the other two, which look same to me (example below), can't be identified by index like `//*[@class='select'][2]`, tried 'following' without success, but I may be not correct with syntax.

Example of dropdown element I'm unable to locate..

```
<a aria-required="false" class="select" aria-disabled="false" aria-
describedby="6280:0-label" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" role="button" 
title="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="6290:0" data-
interactive-lib-uid="16">--None--</a>
```

Any ideas what am I missing?, except advanced xpath knowledge..

Thank you!

Comment: Just found out I have those elements inside different sections, 'class="slds-grid mdp forcePageBlockSectionRow"', and first dropdown element is identified (probably] as I'm inside the first popup section, what syntax I should use to get xpath to locate dropdown inside second section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//*[@class='select'][2]` will return you required node only if both links are children of the same parent, e.g.

```
<div>
    <a class="select">Stage 1 - Needs Assessment</a>
    <a class="select">--None--</a>
</div>
```

If links are children of different parents, e.g.

```
<div>
    <a class="select">Stage 1 - Needs Assessment</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="select">--None--</a>
</div>
```

you should use

```
(//*[@class='select'])[1]
```

for first

```
(//*[@class='select'])[2]
```

for second

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andersson, I'm all set.